# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input moment.min.js:7

Tags: javascript, momentjs

When I use moment.min.js, chrome/FireFox gave me such error"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input moment.min.js:7"
Here is pieces of .html:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/js/headroom.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/js/jQuery.headroom.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/js/template.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/js/moment.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

I tried version 2.6 and 2.8.4 2.8.3, but met the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It be hard to diagnose the problem with that little of information... However most likely the error being cause from a conflicting script(s) which were loaded before it was.